# client is receiving data only after AsnycContext.complete

Tags: spring, tomcat7, asyncsocket, asynchronous

I am using AsyncContext to handle client request asynchronously. In my server side code I am doing something like this.

-> in Controller class, I am retrieving AsyncContext and storing it.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/xyz/")
public void getXyz(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);
map.put("xyz", asyncContext);
```

-> A threadPool in my application receiving messages from MQ and write data on asyncContext
    // convert message into JSON String and then
    // retrieve context from map

```
asyncContext.getResponse().getOutputStream().print(strMessage);
asyncContext.getResponse().getOutputStream().flush();
```

and if this is the final chunk or in case of exception

```
asyncContext.complete();
```

Now, the problem or behavior is my browser which is making GET call, is not receiving the data when server is writing on outputstream but only getting when server is executing

```
asyncContext.complete();
```

I want my browser to receive data as soon as it is written on outputstream (and flushed) and not to wait till asyncContext complete, because it may never get called.

looking for solution like atmosphere broadcaster or HTML5 SSE but using only AyncContext